# '\n' for new line not working in minified js file

Tags: jquery, newline

I am concatinating '\n' to a value placed in a text area. However, it works for my normal js file, but does not work in the minified js file in production environment. I tried '\\n' and it works in minified file, but doesn't work in the normal js file. Can any one suggest any idea that could work in both files.Thanks in advance.

`var logs = j$('#logs').val()+"\nFinished running attendance processor.\nTotal Time taken : "+ totalTime / 1000 + " seconds.";`

---

Editing in update from comments:

The code from min file looks like this...

```
var h=j$("#logs").val()+" Finished running attendance processor. Total Time taken : "
+g/1000+" seconds.";
```

Comment: You might need to show us what it looks like when minefield and tell us what your mini fire is...

Comment: If your minifier breaks this, get a better minifier.

Comment: @Paddy:The code from min file looks like this...var h=j$("#logs").val()+"
Finished running attendance processor.
Total Time taken : "+g/1000+" seconds.";

Comment: @SubirKumarSao That's a space, not a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var NL = String.fromCharCode(10);
var logs = j$('#logs').val()+NL+"Finished running attendance processor."+NL+"Total Time taken : "+ totalTime / 1000 + " seconds.";
```